# Is adding a column to a CQL table a constant time or linear time operation?

Tags: cassandra

When altering a table to add a new column, the Cassandra [documentation](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cassandra/cql/ddl.html#alter-table-statement) states that

```
Adding a column is a constant-time operation based on the amount of data in the table.
```

Though, this may be a bit ambiguous. Does it mean it is linear time as the execution time depends on the amount of data in the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a column to a table takes the same amount of time regardless of how much data is in the table.

If you recall, SSTables (Cassandra data files) are **immutable** -- once they've been written to disk, they *never change*.

When you add a column to a table, nothing actually happens to the existing SSTables -- Cassandra doesn't alter/update/modify the existing files. But if your app writes data to the new column, the newly flushed SSTables will contain the new column.

Similarly, the newly-merged SSTables from the next cycle of compactions will contain the new column. What this means is that adding a new column takes exactly the same amount of time whether a table is empty or contains terrabytes of data.

The thing that is relevant is the cluster topology. Schema changes are propagated via gossip, it doesn't follow the normal write path. The bigger a cluster is, the longer it will take for a schema change to be gossiped to all nodes in a large cluster. Cheers!